# Detection of the He-nuclei in the historical Rutherford scattering experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, atomic-physics, history, particle-detectors

Which method did Rutherford use to detect the Helium nuclei in his [scattering experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_scattering)?

Comment: A zinc selenide screen, as noted in the Geiger-Marsden paper. Such phosphor screens continued to be used for quite some time, well in to the 1930s and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

My comment was incorrect, so I'd better fix it!

In 'On a Diffuse Reflection of the $\alpha$-Particles' by Geiger and Marsden in the Proceedings of the Royal Society, volume 82, issue 557, pages 495-500 (1909), one finds on page 496:

> The zinc suphide screen S (fig.1) was fixed behind the lead plate P, in such a position that no $\alpha$-particles could strike it directly.

So, zinc suphide was the phosphor used.